# Need to know about Facebook Login feature for websites

Tags: python, facebook, flask

I have developed a news aggregation tool using python and i would like to deploy it to facebook etc. I was thinking about utilising the facebook login to know what their likes are so that i can use it to send interesting articles. However, facebook does not have any SDK for python. I could use the PHP SDK but im not sure how i would integrate it with my flask application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is something:

- Python Facebook SDK: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk
- PyFacebook: https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/
- http://www.pythonforfacebook.com
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/ (mentions the same 3rd party Python SDK)

It's always best to google first and then ask! :)

Comment: I have googled, i found that but im not sure how to use it, as there are fewer tutorials. Eitherways Thanks!

Comment: @user2834165: Tutorials/how to use it, is a completely different question—you said there was nothing; I demonstrated there was.

Comment: @user2834165: also, a good option always is to just open the source code of the SDK and read away—Python code is usually understandable enough... so you don't even need a doc; and even if there is one, the source code can be more informative.

Comment: Right. See all i need is a button like any other 'Sign in with Facebook' which imports all of the likes of the person currently logged in.

Comment: @user2834165: OK, I understand that; probably the Javascript SDK is really the most practical in your specific case :) it's just that you also mentioned sending articles etc. so I thought you need a full(er) SDK access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Restful API service for implementing Facebook into python.

**https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/**

There is no big difference in between PHP and python code to understand.

Just convert PHP restful API into python.

Answer (score 0):

Better will be you use javascript SDK of facebook to login from your site.
This is simple.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

To use that you must know about facebook graph API. 
You can find plenty of example on google about facebook JavaScript SDK